# Unexpected string

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять, в чем заключается ошибка? Ошибка:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Ошибка в методе `createImage()`

```js
'use strict'

class Gallery {
  constructor(thumbnail, original) {
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    this.original = original;
  }

  createImage() {
    return '<img src="' + this.thumbnail '">';
  }
}

var images = new Gallery('http://www.pixic.ru/i/2081W44634K5D3r8.jpg', 'http://www.pixic.ru/i/H0n1549674h5k3C9.jpg');

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('gallery').innerHTML = images.createImage();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Gallery</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="gallery"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
createImage() {
    return '<img src="' + this.thumbnail + '">';// Тут была синтаксическая ошибка
}
```

Но лучше:

```
createImage() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.thumbnail;
  return img;
}
```

И потом:

```
document.getElementById('gallery').appendChild(images.createImage());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 return '<img src="' + this.thumbnail + '">';
                                      ^-------- вот этого не хватает
```